# Too many questions about Starlink

Tags: discussion

As of 12:30 UCT on the 15th of January 2020, four of the fifteen newest questions are about Starlink satellites.  Should we consider having one, definitive answer and closing any new questions as duplicates of that?

I guess, though the OPs won't be aware of it at the time of posting, that the questions should also be directed at Space Exploration, rather than here.  Should we be pointing the posters to an answer on there?

Comment: Related: [Do we need a notice about billionaire space ventures?](/q/545)

Comment: Oh no, it's spread to Meta too! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Line of lights moving in a straight line, with a few following](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32034) has been serving as a de facto Original Starlink Question.
I think a community wiki answer there would be appropriate.